# Information of particular locations (points) in a map

Tags: qgis

For a marathon race I need to create a map with specific information about material needed in particular positions (eg crossroads). It's about 150 positions. You see one part in the picture below.

Untill now my company have used Apple Pages and we had to adapt every changes by hand. I would now like to use GIS.

I'm used to ArcGIS which is too expensive to afford for the company I work for. Thus, I came to QGIS.

Is it possible to create such a map in QGIS or how would you recommend to proceed?

Honestly, I am not even sure how to do it in ArcGIS.

[image]

Comment: Actually it is an non profit project but outsourced to my company, which is commercial. I also thought about this. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this using QGIS (v2.6.1):

- You could create a **Points** layer to create your points (using the OpenLayers plugin as a reference) and include any information in the attributes table.

[image: Points layer]

You can then show your information (attributes) via *labeling*:

[image: Labeling]

---

- You could also use **Text Annotations** which are only saved in your **project file (.prj)**:

[image: Text annotation]

Select the text annotation icon and click anyway on the canvas to create an annotation. Double left-click on the annotation to access its options:

[image: Text annotation options]

Just remember to save your project file.

Comment: I would propose you use the first option, where you save the information on each on every point ( and not use text annotations). 
When you have all your information linked to the features, you can more easily get an overview/print/sum of everything by using the Attribute Table (rightclick layer -> open attribute Table)

Comment: @Max - Thanks buddy, I also agree with using the Points layer and saving the attributes. I very much prefer having information stored in shapefiles for processing. I only added Text Annotations as it is visually closer to the image the OP posted :)

Comment: Thank you both for your answer. :D This is what I was looking for! one more question: I'd prefer to add an attribute table with all the required information. This should also be possible, though?

Comment: @Joseph: Did you do this using ArcGIS or QGIS? It does not look similar to my version of ArcGIS (10.somewhat) but you'd prefered ArcGIS to QGIS.

Comment: @KevinSuhr - Doh! Apologies, forgot to mention I used QGIS for this (v2.6.1). As per your previous question, yes you can add attributes to a point layer by right-clicking the layer and accessing its **Attributes Table**. There you can add fields (columns) and all your data for each point.

Comment: @Joseph: awesome! ArcGIS won't work. We use Macs in the Office and I forgot ArcGIS does not work on Macs. Or is it possible  So, it will be QGIS. And I think I can also import and Excel-File (csv) into QGIS as it is possible in ArcGIS?

Comment: @KevinSuhr - It is mentioned [here](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/system-requirements) that ArcGIS is not supported for MAC. And you are correct, QGIS can import/export .csv files =)

Comment: @Joseph: actually I know this...but I was somehow too enthusiastic about your solution and my idea to use GIS..;-) Thank you very much for your supoort!

Comment: @KevinSuhr - Most welcome buddy!

Comment: @Joseph: The first way you proposed: Is it somehow possible to connect the text and the point with a line? and second: I don't get it to insert more than attribute to each point. In the layer properties I can only chose one, eg. ID or Name. Thank you again!

Comment: @KevinSuhr - It is generally advised that you ask a new question as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and not through comments :). Saying that, for your first question: I don't think it's possible, you may have to create a separate line layer for this; secondly, this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45365/how-to-create-vertical-labels-in-qgis) answers your labelling issue.

Comment: ok. I didn't know that. Sorry for that and thanks for the infos :D